# C++ Syntax in ImGui: Three dots

Tags: c++, templates, format, imgui

I found the following code in a cpp files of the [ImGui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/imgui_widgets.cpp#L264) library. What does this signature mean in C++ please:

```
void ImGui::Text(const char* fmt, ...);
```

Is this a type of parameter pack which looks different:

```
template<class... Args>
void op(Args... args);
```

Comment: The is just a [`variadic function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic).  Nothing to do with parameter packs or templates.  Should be a dupe somewhere.

Comment: It is a [variadic function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic) (not to be confused with _variadic template_ which is completely unrelated). It is a C feature actually, a function accepting an unspecified number of arguments of unspecified type. It is how `printf` etc. work. The function probably just forwards to `sprintf`. Except for interfacing with C there is basically no good reason to use variadic functions in C. They are pretty dangerous because there is no type safety on the arguments at all.